# Shell script: list all entries that don't contain a number

Tags: bash, shell, glob, ls

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
ls * [!0-9] * .*
```

but that doesn't work - I still get some files that contain a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
shopt extglob
```

says

```
extglob         on
```

then you can try

```
ls !(*[0-9]*)
```

Use the following to enable this option

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: +1. If you wanted to robustly process all matching files inside the script, you can use `for f in !(*[0-9]*); do ...; done`

Answer (score 2):

how about good ol grep like so ... `ls | grep -v "[0-9]"`

Note: removed the `*` as suggested by BMW.

Comment: Nice alternative to having to deal with the `extglob` shell option.

Comment: what's the reason using ls with `*`?

Comment: @BMW you are correct. Just `ls | grep -v "[0-9]"` would have sufficed.